# Header links with picture in the horizontal center

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to put a picture in the center of a header 10% from the top. I will have 5 links on the header each with varying string lengths, and I don't want it to effect the position of the picture in the center. There will be 2 links on the left side of the image, and 3 of the right.

Comment: Can you please provide the code you've already tried?

Answer (score -1):

```css
/* Reset some default styles for the header and links */
header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #333; /* Header background color */
    padding: 10px; /* Adjust as needed */
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff; /* Link text color */
    margin: 0 10px; /* Adjust as needed */
}

/* Center the image vertically and horizontally */
.header-center {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-grow: 1; /* Allow the center div to grow and take available space */
}

/* Adjust the image size as needed */
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Header with Centered Image and Links</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="header-left">
            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        </div>
        <div class="header-center">
            <img src="your-image.jpg" alt="Centered Image">
        </div>
        <div class="header-right">
            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
            <a href="#">Link 4</a>
            <a href="#">Link 5</a>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, ChatGPT answers are forbidden. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1. And if you want to claim it's not ChatGPT, I ran the question through it myself and got a code sample virtually identical to what you posted